# Pass variable to Controller when clear button is clicked rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "cc_banker_assignments", action: "index"}, method: "get", class: "form-horizontal") do %>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <span class="badge badge-error count-error"></span>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Date of Assignment</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <%= text_field_tag "assignment_date", params[:assignment_date], class: "form-control", id: "date-range" %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 1.5em;">
          <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Assigned To</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <%= select_tag "assigned_to", options_from_collection_for_select(@banker, :id, :name, params[:assigned_to]), class: 'form-control single-select', prompt: "All Bankers" %>
          </div>
        </div>
<div class="col-sm-8 pull-right" style="margin-top: -0.3em">
            <%= submit_tag "Search", :class => "btn btn-default lender-search-btn btn-s-layout" %>
            <%= button_tag "Clear", :type => 'reset', :class => "btn btn-primary btn-c-layout clear_button", :onClick => "check_for_cancel" %> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Ok so i have this form and i want to be able to pass a variable to my index method on my controller when i click on the button.

This is because i want my controller to know if the clear button has been clicked and the only way for me to do tht is to pass a variable to my controller index method.

my controller method

```
def index


    @banker = Banker.where("locked_at is null and approved = true").order('name asc')

    ap params
    if !params[:get_status].nil?
      params[:banker_status] = BankerAssignmentStatus.where("assignment_status =? ",params[:get_status]).pluck(:id)
    end
    search_banker_assignment params

    render template: 'cc_banker_assignments/index'
  end
```

How do i do this using rails

Comment: Is clear button is submitting the form? or if you want to pass value on form submission, add and `hidden_field_tag`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to clear the form inputs by requesting index page? You can use link_to instead of button_tag to do that, or just javascript. If you really want to pass a variable to the controller, you can bind your button to a jQuery.ajax() call.